# Can one suppress the conversation propagation with an `<h:link>`?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi

I'm using the new JSF2 `<h:link>` tag, with a nested `<f:param>` to link to a page using a get request.  However, the conversation id (cid) is propagated via the query parambeters of the link to the new page.

Can one suppress the conversation propagation with an `<h:link>`?  ie. no cid=# in the url...?

Comment: I rolled back the changes to my tags for the following reasons:

1) Conversations in JavaEE 6 are not available without CDI
2) the <h:link> tag is available only in jsf2

Comment: Please stop removing the "cdi" tag.  Conversation are not available in jsf without cdi.

Comment: sorry, as you didn't mention CDI explicitely, I assumed you mistyped "cid". As for the JSF tag - JSF2 is still JSF. The JSF tag isn't fixed for jsf 1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug with Weld, the reference implementation of JSR-299:

https://jira.jboss.org/browse/WELD-549

> The spec requires an explicit f:param for h:link

Meaning one is supposed to explicitly include the ?cid=# with an f:param, and it should not be there by default.

Comment: Did you find any workarounds for this problem? This problem is annoying, cause you get exceptions when the conversation times out, although you're on a non-conversation-page.

Comment: Nope, no workaround per se.  I just changed a bunch of stuff to viewParams, so I could begin the conversation at a later stage.  An overall improvement.